# How to retain blanks in group by in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I need to `groupby` my DataFrame in pandas but when I am doing that the null values are converting into zero, but I want to retain nulls. I am not sure how to do that in pandas.

Input:

```
Id  Country  Product  sales  qty  price
1   Germany  shoes    32      1   NaN
1   Germany  shoes    32      1    2
2   England  Shoes    22      1   NaN
2   England  Shoes    22      1   NaN
3   Austria  Shoes    0       3   NaN
3   Austria  Shoes    NaN     NaN NaN
```

Desired output:

```
Id  Country  Product  sales  qty  price
1   Germany  shoes    64      2   2
2   England  Shoes    44      2   NaN
3   Austria  Shoes    0       3   NaN
```

Comment: Solution with `min_count=1` for you not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `mask` it using `isna` + `group` + `all`

```
out = (df.groupby(['Id','Country','Product']).sum()
       .mask(df[['sales','qty','price']].isna()
             .groupby([df['Id'], df['Country'], df['Product']]).all())
       .reset_index())
```

The same idea written differently:

```
cols = ['Id','Country','Product']
g = df.groupby(cols)
out = (g.sum()
       .mask(g.apply(lambda x: x.drop(columns=cols).isna().all()))
       .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   Id  Country Product  sales  qty  price
0   1  Germany   shoes   64.0  2.0    2.0
1   2  England   Shoes   44.0  2.0    NaN
2   3  Austria   Shoes    0.0  3.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter `min_count=1` in [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['Id','Country','Product'], as_index=False).sum(min_count=1)
print (df)
   Id  Country Product  sales  qty  price
0   1  Germany   shoes   64.0  2.0    2.0
1   2  England   Shoes   44.0  2.0    NaN
2   3  Austria   Shoes    0.0  3.0    NaN
```